# Showing <p> when radio button selected

Tags: javascript, html, addeventlistener

I'm quite new to JS + HTML but basically i want 4 radio buttons, each with a different name like this

```
o PS4
o Xbox
o Nintendo DS
```

When one of these is clicked/checked, i want to output the price which will be held in a "p" next to them, as shown

```
o PS4   £400
""
""
```

The price is then hidden when the next is clicked, and the corresponding price for that is then shown, ive spent hours and hours trying to search for this and test things, but nothing seems to work, so ANY help is greatly appreciated

Thanks,

Dan

Comment: How can we help you if you don't post any code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that works perfectly fine:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".price").hide();
$("input").click(function(){
 $(".price").hide();
  $(this).siblings().show();
});
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
<span>
<input type="radio" name="drink" value="vodka"/>Vodka <span  class="price">$40</span><br />
</span>
<span>
<input type="radio" name="drink" value="beer"/>Beer <span class="price">$50</span><br />
</span>
<span>
<input type="radio" name="drink" value="juice"/>Juice <span class="price">$20</span><br />
</span> 
</form>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

or try this jsfiddle directly here:
https://jsfiddle.net/balyancoder/dbgkfw0f/

Comment: "$" is not defined, im assuming im using a different textedit or something maybe?

Comment: $ is used by jquery. Make sure you have included the link to jquery to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a plain JavaScript example:

```
<form id="form">
  <label>
    <input name="console" type="radio" value="400">PS4</label>
  <label>
    <input name="console" type="radio" value="350">XBox</label>
  <label>
    <input name="console" type="radio" value="200">Nintendo DS</label>
</form>
<br>
<div>Price:
  <div id="price"></div>
</div>
```

JavaScript (Using ES6)

```
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('change', () => {

  const radios = document.getElementsByName('console');

  Object.keys(radios).forEach((obj, i) => {
    if (radios[i].checked) {
      price = document.getElementById('price');
      price.innerHTML = `<p>£${radios[i].value}</p>`;
    }
  });

});
```

Sample:
[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/exfsa1qs/)

Comment: Thankyou so much for your help i appreciate it greatly, upon opening the console im getting an error stating Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at theatrep2.js:1           Any ideas?

Comment: @Acryaz can you put your code into a JsFiddle, I can then see and help you fix it! :-)

Comment: of course! thanks a lot Matt, the console pricing was an example, the real thing is ticket prices, but console prices are fine i can just edit the names.     https://jsfiddle.net/hqrcvfnj/#&togetherjs=Cpn9LDr5wb

Comment: You are a hero sir thankyou, it works like that in the jsfiddle, but when i use that exact code as shown in the fiddle, i still get the eventlistener null error on the first line, heres a Gyazo of it Matt https://gyazo.com/74f46fdfceb2e1095bd5bce16c3d184f       in case you need to know, im using brackets to edit my code, then running the HTML file with chrome

Comment: I GOT IT WORKING!  i seperated one line into 2, document.getElementById("form")/line break/.addEventListener("change", () => {

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using plain javascript and paragraph tag along with every radio button:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li class="element"><input type="radio" class="radio_btn" name="my_radio">my radio 1
        <p class="parag">price 1</p>
    </li>
    <li class="element"><input type="radio" class="radio_btn" name="my_radio">my radio 2
        <p class="parag">price 2</p>
    </li>
    <li class="element"><input type="radio" class="radio_btn" name="my_radio">my radio 3
        <p class="parag">price 3</p>
    </li>
    <li class="element"><input type="radio" class="radio_btn" name="my_radio">my radio 4
        <p class="parag">price 4</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var radios = document.getElementsByClassName("radio_btn");
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
    radios[i].addEventListener(
        'click',
        function() {
            var parags = document.getElementsByClassName("parag");
            for (var i = 0; i < parags.length; i++) {
                parags[i].style.display = "none";
            }
            this.nextElementSibling.style.display = "inline-block";
        }
    );
}
```

Here [is](https://jsfiddle.net/s2r82k1t/5/) the sample on JSFiddle

Comment: Nice example, adding the event lister within the iteration! :-)